# Attach matplotlib figure.Figure to pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that returns a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object given some parameters and I want to add it to the `pyplot` object (so that `pyplot.show()` shows the image).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

**Background:**

My question may seem counterintuitive, this is why I need to do so. I'm developing a Python package that uses matplotlib to generate plots, so I'm using the OO matplotlib interface.

I'm writing tests (using `matplotlib.testing`, which lets me compare images with a decorator) to be sure that the functions return the correct plots. The problem is that such package uses the MATLAB-like interface and looks for plots in the pyplot object (using `plt.get_fignums()`) and then compares with images in files.

I could modify the `matplotlib.testing` code to suit my needs but using the code as is seems a better option, even though attaching a figure to pyplot seems hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another approach to solve my testing problem. Instead of using the `matplotlib.testing` built-in decorator, I'm using the function that compares the images:

```
from matplotlib.testing.compare import compare_images

compare_images(expected='expected.png', actual='actual.png', tol=13, in_decorator=True)
```

That returns `None` if the test was successful or a Dictionary with some data in case the images differed more than the threshold. I'm going to build a wrapper around that function to make it more testing friendly.